# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined angular6

Tags: firebase, angular6

Have below piece of code:

```
getRegistrations(){
  this.registrationList = this.firebase.list('registrations');
  return this.registrationList.snapshotChanges();
}

insertRegistration(registration){
  this.registrationList.push({
    firstname: registration.firstname,
    lastname: registration.lastname,
    phone: registration.phone,
    email: registration.email,
    password: registration.password
  });
}
```

Getting below error:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Comment: I m not sure about its type: check `typeof(this.registrationList)` inside `insertRegistration` method:

Answer (score 0):

Try This,

```
insertRegistration(registration){
  this.registrationList = [];
  this.registrationList.push({
  firstname: registration.firstname,
  lastname: registration.lastname,
  phone: registration.phone,
  email: registration.email,
  password: registration.password
  });
  }
```

Comment: Does array have snapshotChanges() method?

Answer (score 0):

> Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

This is because of **`this.registrationList`** is getting `undefined` when you are calling **`insertRegistration()`** or you are not Initializing it.

You can check the value if it and In case it's `undefined` then assign empty array to it.

```
  getRegistrations() {
     this.registrationList = this.firebase.list('registrations');
     return this.registrationList.snapshotChanges();
  }

  insertRegistration(registration) {
     this.registrationList = this.registrationList : this.registrationList ? [];
     this.registrationList.push({
       firstname: registration.firstname,
       lastname: registration.lastname,
       phone: registration.phone,
       email: registration.email,
       password: registration.password
    });
  }
```

I hope this will work.. :)

Comment: Does array have `snapshotChanges()` method?

Comment: @PrashantPimpale OP's question is not detailed about `snapshotChanges()` with `this.registrationList`, but surely this answer can helps him out with actual question.

Comment: I add the getRegistrations to my ngsubmit function, and then it works, but i think that function does call insertRgistration

Comment: I can't see any relation between these two `insertRegistration()` , `getRegistrations()` but make sure that  `insertRegistration()` calling from how any other resource than `getRegistrations()`.